# TYPO3 Formhandler input field as additionalParam

Tags: redirect, parameters, get, typo3, typoscript

I am currently constructing a registration system that connects the application process (Formhandler) with the payment process (custom extension) via a redirect.

As a part of this connection, I want to pass a value from the Formhandler to my custom extension through a GET parameter. The Formhandler template contains a hidden field for this value, the value is set by JavaScript:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formhandler[orderid]" id="orderid" value="###value_orderid###" />
```

The TypoScript for the Formhandler contains this finisher:

```
4.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Redirect
4.config {
  additionalParams { 
    order = TEXT 
    order.value = orderid
  }
}
```

But after the successful redirect, the URL looks like this:

```
xxxxxx/zahlungen/?order=orderid
```

The Finisher does not pass the value, instead it sets the field name as a text. What am I doing wrong? I want it to look like this, for example:

```
xxxxxx/zahlungen/?order=12345
```

I have also included a finisher that writes the values into the database and this works flawlessly:

```
3.class = Finisher_DB
3.config{
  table = tx_chilifhregistration
  key = uid

  fields {
    orderid.mapping = orderid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could work for your needs when you add `insertData`:

```
4.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Redirect
4.config {
  additionalParams { 
    order = TEXT 
    order.data = orderid
    order.insertData = 1
  }
}
```

If it doesn't try to get the value directly with `order.value = GPvar:formhandler|orderid`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, neither of these work. If I just add `order.insertData = 1` nothing changes at all, if I use `order.value = GPvar:formhandler|orderid`, the resulting URL reads `xxxxxx/zahlungen/?order=GPvar%3Aformhandler%7Corderid`.

Comment: I got it! As you suggested, it needs `insertData`, but it also needs `order.data = GP:formhandler|orderid`. Not `order.value`, but `order.data`. Thank you!